# onTouch, onLongClick together in Android

Tags: android, event-handling, touch-event, onlongclicklistener, ontouch

I'm adding ImageViews to parent layout dynamically and performing zoom in/out operations with `onTouch` on the added image.

I want to remove the added view with an `onLongPress` of it.

```
img.setOnLongClickListener(longClickAction);
img.setOnTouchListener(touchAction);
```

onLongPress:

```
OnLongClickListener longClickAction = new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        parentLayout.removeView((ImageView)v);
        return false;
    }
};
```

onTouch:

```
OnTouchListener touchAction = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView i = (ImageView)v;

        // Perform zoom operation onTouch of ImageView
        zoom(i, event);
        return true; 
    }
};
```

Why do only the onTouch events work?

How can I get them both to work?

What should I do to remove the added view?

Comment: @Siddhesh follow my [below answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41952363/4629101), the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`onTouch` is always called for your view since this is the initial state of dispatching the events to the view. When you long press your view this still calls `onTouch` first and since you return `true` in `onTouch`(which means that you've consumed this event and it should not be further dispatched) you won't get `onLongPress` called. What will do the trick is returning `false` in `onTouch`

Comment: But then `onTouch` and `onLongPress` will both be called. What about if `onLongPress` means not to call `onTouch`?

Comment: @LuisA.Florit: have you find any solution for this ? same problem with me, both onTouch and onLongPress are called at a time..

Answer (score 2):

As discussed by [@asenovm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10946881/4629101) **The onTouch() is always called as it is the initial state of dispatching the events to the view,** but if we return value **false** in **onTouch()** Then both will work like a charm and the **problem will be solved.**

**Edit:** My suggestion to the users is that instead of implementing  OnLongClickListener() and OnTouch() together, try using the function of OnLongClickListener() in **Double click** event.

**You can implement Double Click in following ways:**

```
int i = 0;
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    i++;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            i = 0;
        }
    };

    if (i == 1) {
        //Single click
        handler.postDelayed(r, 250);
    } else if (i == 2) {
        //Double click
        i = 0;
        ShowDailog();
    }


  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it works fine for me.

```
boolean isMoving= false;

yourView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            isMoving = true;
            Log.i("isMoving:", "true");
        }
        if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            isMoving=false;
            Log.i("isMoving:","false");
        }
        return false;
    }
});
yourView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if(!isMoving){
            //do onlongclick event here
        }
        return true;
    }
});;
```

Answer (score 0):

[Dynamically remove controls](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10515816/1438915)

may help you

[using onTouch and onLongClick](http://androidforums.com/application-development/17033-ontouch-onlongclick-together.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you need finger to be still then the simpliest way to do it in **Kotlin** is like this

in *onCreateView* :

```
view.setOnTouchListener(this)
view.setOnClickListener(this)
view.setOnLongClickListener {
    if (! isFingerMoving) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Long click detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        //do something
    }
    false
}
```

in *onTouch* :

```
fun onTouch(v: View?, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    when (event.actionMasked) {
        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
            isFingerMoving = false
            lastTouchX = event.getX(0)
            lastTouchY = event.getY(0)
            ...
        }
        
        MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE -> {
            val deltaX = (x - lastTouchX) * event.xPrecision
            val deltaY = (y - lastTouchY) * event.yPrecision
            if ((deltaX.absoluteValue > 0.1) || (deltaY.absoluteValue > 0.1)) 
                isFingerMoving = true            
            ...                 
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cant achive this togither by setOnLongClickListener and setOnTouchListener
because when you return true inside onTouch method it assume that you handle all touch events  you can achieve long click by post delay and call method after time out but you need to check if is still pressing or action up fired
may be this code snapshot help you

```
 mBinding.iv2.setOnTouchListener(object : View.OnTouchListener {

        var stillPress = false
        override fun onTouch(view: View?, motionEvent: MotionEvent?): Boolean {
            if(motionEvent?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                 stillPress = true
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                    if(stillPress)
                        zoomImageFromThumb(view!!,R.drawable.ic_baseline_adb_24)
                },1000)
            }

            if(motionEvent?.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                stillPress = false
                mBinding.expandedImage.performClick()
            }
            return true

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the **onLongPress** Method from the **GestureDetecter** class and pass in the **onTouch** Method of the corresponding View.