# Disable specific mouse event on image in Safari (ipad) using js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, mouseevent

Currently I have a image file. By default, if I long tap on that image file, an option of "save image /copy" is shown. And I personally add a doubletap event on it.

The problem is:
I need a double tap event but not long tap event

What I found on the internet is one can simply add a `pointer event : none` in the img style to disable all mouse event , however, what if I just want to disable the long tap event?

From doc,

pointer-events:  auto | none | visiblePainted | visibleFill | visibleStroke | visible | painted | fill | stroke | all | inherit

But are there any parmeter is suitable for my case? Thanks

Comment: usually adding something to the tag like on<someevent>="return false" will work ... or have it call a function with preventDefault() + an IE workaround

Comment: here is a function example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946751/ontouch-onlongclick-together-in-android