# Ontouch and onclick in android list item

Tags: android, android-listview, swipe, baseadapter, ontouchlistener

I want to implement the ontouch and onclicklistener in android listview item.

If i have selecting the row and click a row., need to call onclicklistener.

at the same time If I have swiping the list row on left and right ., need to call ontouchlistener in adapter file.

how can i do ? please give me a solution for this ?

here swipe working fine.but onclick is not calling from my code.

In activity file.,

```
class MyUpcomingTouchListener implements OnTouchListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        ViewHolder1 holder = (ViewHolder1) v.getTag(R.layout.listof_upcoming);
        int action = event.getAction();
        int position = (Integer) v.getTag();

        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            action_down_x = (int) event.getX();
            Log.d("action", "ACTION_DOWN - ");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            Log.d("action", "ACTION_MOVE - ");
            action_up_x = (int) event.getX();
            difference = action_down_x - action_up_x;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.d("action", "ACTION_UP - ");
            calcuateupcomingDifference(holder, position);
            action_down_x = 0;
            action_up_x = 0;
            difference = 0;
            break;
        }
        return true;

    }

}
private void calcuateupcomingDifference(final ViewHolder1 holder, final int position) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (difference == 0) {
            }
            if (difference > 90) {
                holder.carudetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.carucheckin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.caruimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                upcomingitems.get(position).setVisible(true);
                upcominglistAdapter.changeData(upcomingitems);
            }
            if (difference < -90) {
                holder.carudetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.carucheckin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.caruimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                upcomingitems.get(position).setVisible(true);
                upcominglistAdapter.changeData(upcomingitems);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

From the adapter file,

```
 convertView.setOnTouchListener(mOnTouchListener);
 convertView.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(TodayList.this,
                            DetailPage.class);
                startActivity(intent);
               }});
```

Comment: do you want to perform onClick on the all View that represents the row of List or on some special item of the row?

Comment: i need to perform the onclick() functionaliy on selected row of the list.

Comment: use gesture listener on your list view item it will provide both touch as well as click listener..

Answer (score 0):

To perfrom onClick on a row of ListView you should use onItemClickListener,set it via list.setOnItemClickListener(). If you want to provide this from the adapter,then it will be better to use GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener,where you have events like scroll,double tap,single tap up.
Also if you want to perform onClick from the code you have now, you can try:

```
private void calcuateupcomingDifference(final ViewHolder1 holder, final int position) {
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override 
    public void run() { 
         int absValue=Math.abs(difference);
        if (absValue >= 0 && absValue<=10) {
           holder.rowLayout.performOnClick(); 
        } 
        if (difference > 90) { 
            holder.carudetails.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.carucheckin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.caruimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            upcomingitems.get(position).setVisible(true);
            upcominglistAdapter.changeData(upcomingitems); 
        } 
        if (difference < -90) { 
            holder.carudetails.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.carucheckin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.caruimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            upcomingitems.get(position).setVisible(true);
            upcominglistAdapter.changeData(upcomingitems); 
        } 
    } 
});
// DO not forget to add the rowLayout of converView to ViewHolder1 and to set rowLayout.setOnClickListener();
```

Comment: Already i have tried with your's logic.it means i have swiping the row., the onclick functionality only working at that time ontouch functionality was not working.ok i will go another way GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener

Comment: I'm a little bit busy now,and can not test the code and say for 100% will it work or not,but at least a gave you a start point. hope it will help. If i will find some time i will test and post the results.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

Return `false` on your `"ACTION_DOWN"` on your activity file like below:

```
class MyUpcomingTouchListener implements OnTouchListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ...
        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            ...
            return false;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            ...
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            ...
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Explanation:

`onTouch` is always called upon pressing the view since this is the initial state of dispatching the events to the view. When you long
press your view this still calls `onTouch` first and since you
previously returned `true` in `onTouch` (which means that you've consumed
this event and it should not be further dispatched) you won't get `onLongPress` called. What will do the trick is returning `false` in `onTouch`.

Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10946881/3603195) answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use another variable (boolean isClick):

```
        rowView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private float startX;
        private boolean isSwipeActive;
        private boolean isClick;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startX = event.getX();
                    isClick = true;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    isSwipeActive = true;
                    float deltaX = event.getX() - startX;
                    if (isSwipeActive && deltaX < -1 ) {
                        isClick = false;
                        holder.buttonsLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.mainContentLayout.animate().x(-150).y(0).setDuration(500);
                        item_list.get(position).isSwiped = true;
                    }else if (isSwipeActive && deltaX > 1 ) {
                        isClick = false;
                        holder.mainContentLayout.animate().x(0).y(0).setDuration(500);
                        Handler handler = new Handler();
                        Runnable runnable = () -> holder.buttonsLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 500);
                        item_list.get(position).isSwiped = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    isSwipeActive = false;
                    if(isClick) rowView.performClick();
                    isClick = false;
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```