# Handle Listview longClick

Tags: android, listview, onlongclicklistener, gesturedetector, gesturelistener

I have listview in RelativeLayout. 
I want to listen for left/right swipes and single/long clicks. 
For listen swipes I use instance of SimpleOnGestureListener, which I return in -

```
listView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        });
```

In this case I cant listen for long clicks because **SimpleOnGestureListener**'s method  - **onLongPress** returns void. Is there way to listen for long click exactly in listview's OnItemLongClickListener method and also listen swipes? Thanks.

Comment: For listing swipe better go for `RecycleView` because `ListView` is going to be depricated

Comment: Ok, I will try to use it in future project.
And for now is there way to handle Long Click in ListView?

Comment: As the answer mention by @SohailZahid is the best way to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed ListView to RecyclerView like Burhanuddin Rashid  [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38975724/handle-listview-longclick#comment65305100_38975724)

Answer (score 0):

```
lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int pos, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: it will but you have add some extra code ..... it is fine and easy with same functionality.

Comment: you can find it here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6519748/how-to-determine-a-long-touch-on-android

Comment: if it help you can tick mark or vote up thanks happy coding:)